# Do immutable types need copy constructors?

Tags: java, immutability

Say I have an immutable `DecimalNumber` class:

```
public final class DecimalNumber {

    public final String str;

    public DecimalNumber(String str) { this.str = str; }
    public DecimalNumber(DecimalNumber copy) { this(copy.str); }

    public boolean isZero() {...}

    public DecimalNumber add(DecimalNumber other) {...}

    ...

}
```

and I decide to implement `add` like this:

```
public DecimalNumber add(DecimalNumber other) {

    if (other.isZero())
        return /* the same object */

    ...

}
```

Should I return `this` (less memory use) or a copied object `new DecimalNumber(this)`?

I would think simply returning `this` should be fine but is there ever a benefit to or reason for creating a new object or is it ever preferred?

Comment: For me the large benefit of an Immutable is to be able to pass it around as I please as I do not need to fear it might be changed by anyone. So I'd return `this`.

Comment: I'd return `this` for memory and performance reasons (although the gain wouldn't be huge) as well as logical reasons. If the numbers are immutable anyways then why should there ever be two instances of it (except if you'd want to deliberately break `==` semantics which shouldn't be used for comparison anyways)?

Comment: return this might be good option @Thomas I agree with you comment

Comment: As an aside, if the object is final, you don’t need the copy constructor, `public DecimalNumber(DecimalNumber copy)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a class is immutable and final, then you can return `this`.

If it is not final, you cannot be sure that the `this` instance is really immutable. You might actually be dealing with a subclass which adds mutable state.

Note that a class is only really immutable if:

- All its fields are final, even the private ones. (Because of the Java memory model allowing other threads to see unfinished/default values for non-final fields, a non-final field with only a getter does not suffice.)
- All its fields are either of immutable classes themselves, or access to them is restricted so that you can be sure they will never be changed.

In your case these two conditions are met, since `String` is an immutable class. If you known that no subclasses of your class exist, then you can (in fact, should IMHO) return `this`. To make sure that no subclasses of your class can exist, you can make it `final`.

Answer (score 2):

As you object is immutable, we need to create another copy whenever we **change** it. But here, adding zero will not change the value of the object.
Hence, we can return the same object.

Consider the `concat()` code from String.java for reference:

```
public String concat(String str) {
        int otherLen = str.length();
        if (otherLen == 0) {
            return this;
        }
        char buf[] = new char[count + otherLen];
        getChars(0, count, buf, 0);
        str.getChars(0, otherLen, buf, count);
        return new String(0, count + otherLen, buf);
    }
```

As you can see, there is no harm in returning the same object.

Answer (score 1):

why do you feel strange about returning `this`?

If you would return a new object you would not need the `if` in the first place, so returning `new DecimalNumber(this)` is no option at all!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to ever make a copy of an immutable value object. Since it's immutable, both the original and copy will be equivalent for all time, and thus having two copies is nonsensical.

Not only would I `return this` in your example, I would go one step further and completely delete your copy constructor.

As an example, the Java `String` class actually has a copy constructor. But all that this is done is led to code by inexperienced developers who either don't realize it's immutable (or don't understand what that implies), so they do `new String(aString)` or `new String("Hello")`, which does nothing but waste memory and processor cycles.

Answer (score 0):

I would return this, if an object is really immutable. You simply do not need two instances that will be surely always equal.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html

Comment: In this case it is. The string is final.

Comment: sorry i did not see the the final keyword